# SCCM | How to create a report to show Hardware count and then OS (per HW count)

Tags: reporting-services, sccm

I never created a report in SCCM and I always used the inbuilt ones but now I need to track my PC's models per OS and I cannot find a report that can help me.
Looking online I found a few posts about counting the total of hardware models but nothing that would have the OS together in it.
 [Posts like](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2541302e-f9bd-41ad-91cb-2f669a0df97c/count-computers-by-model-number?forum=configmgrgeneral)
[Posts like](https://silentcrash.com/2018/01/sccm-report-count-computers-model/)
Could you guys help me with this please? the end result would be:
Model         Windows 10 Windows 7 Windows Server 
DELL model 1   10           20          10
HP   model 2   10            67         34

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the [example](https://silentcrash.com/2018/01/sccm-report-count-computers-model/) you already found, the query would look something like this

```
select      cs.Model0, os.Caption0, count(*) as Count 
from        v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM cs
left join   v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM os 
on          cs.ResourceID = os.ResourceID
group by    cs.Model0, os.Caption0
order by    cs.Model0
```

so the solution is to use the so called "grouping sets" and group by more than one property which you joined from another table

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the code. I just noticed we dont have any reports setup so I need to start from scratch - how to setup reports in SCCM.!!!

Comment: Normally you can just open the website of the reportserver (something like http://<reportserver>/reports with a user that has sufficient rights to create reports and then use the button "new" -> "paginated report" to create one. Might be possible to install the report builder manually before (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613 this owuld be the one for sql server 2016 e.g.) but could also be that you are prompted. Might also be that in order to connect you need a certificate from the server. also:https://www.systemcenterdudes.com/sccm-report-creation-report-builder/